# Speeding up nearest Neighbor with scipy.spatial.cKDTree

Tags: python, scipy, distance, nearest-neighbor, scipy-spatial

I'm trying to optimize my nearest neighbor distance code that I need to calculate for many iterations of the same dataset

I am calculating the nearest neighbor distance for the points in dataset A, to the points in dataset B. Both datasets contain ~ (1000-2000) 2-dimensional points. While the points in dataset A stay the same, I have lots of different iterations for dataset B (~100000), B<sub>0</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>, ...B<sub>100000</sub>.I wonder if I can somehow speed this up given that A stays the same.

To calculate the nearest neighbor distances I use

```
for i in range(100000):
   tree = spatial.cKDTree(B[i])
   mindist1, minid = tree.query(A)   
   score[i] = np.mean(mindist1**4))**0.25
   # And some other calculations
   ...
```

I wonder if there is a way to speed this up given `A` stays the same throughout the entire loop. It seems to me like there should be a smarter way to do this given that A is the same.